# Can not get current output pin state on Arduino Due

Tags: toggle, arduino

I have a simple task of toggling an output pin state on Arduino Due using Arduino IDE 1.5.2.
I have tried the code like this:

```
int pinnum = 13;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pinnum, OUTPUT);  // use on-board LED
} 

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pinnum, !digitalRead(pinnum));
  delay(1000);  // wait around for 1 sec (1000 ms)
}
```

This does nothing. Pin 13 stays HIGH all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi I deleted my answer as it was no help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160963/how-can-i-digitalread-a-pin-that-is-in-pinmode-output I think you should be able to get something working from this url tho,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug when reading the state of a pin set as OUTPUT. As a temporary workaround, set the pin as an input at some point before setting it as an output if your circuit allows, like so:

```
int pinnum = 13;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pinnum, INPUT);   // Work around bug
  pinMode(pinnum, OUTPUT);  // use on-board LED
} 

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pinnum, !digitalRead(pinnum));
  delay(1000);  // wait around for 1 sec (1000 ms)
}
```

For more details, see my post at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=185291.0.

EDIT: Sorry for my previous terrible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you cannot read the digital value that you previously 
sent to pin 13. You always read a low level since an LED is connected to ground.

**Solution**: Have a copy of the logic level you send to pin 13 stored in a variable.
This variable I name `mem` in my code below. You don't need to read pin 13
because now you have a copy in `mem`. This copy you invert before sending it to pin 13
as you have done in your code example.

Your problem is usually described as a warning when performing read-modify-write operations on port pins—refer to the datasheet taken from the microcontroller manufacturer.

```
int pinnum = 13;
int mem = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pinnum, OUTPUT);  // use on-board LED
} 

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(pinnum, mem);
  mem=!mem;
  delay(1000);  // wait around for 1 sec (1000 ms)
}
```